# Nokia 3109c freezed on java app when calling System.getProperty("wireless.messaging.sms.smsc")

Tags: java, java-me

in my app in method **startApp()** I want to detect if a simcard is inserted in phone or not by this code:

```
try {
        String s = System.getProperty("wireless.messaging.sms.smsc");
        if (s == null) {
            simCard = false;
        } else {
            simCard = true;
        } 
    } catch (Exception e) {
        simCard = false;
    }
```

This works well on emulator, Nokia 2700 and Nokia 5230. But this failed on Nokia **3109c**. When I open my application on Nokia **3109c**, phone **freezes** with screen "Opening application" and progress bar.

I dont know why it is happening. If someone could help me, I will appreciate it. Thank You.

Comment: Do you know which version of Series 40 runs on 3109c? http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Java_ME_API_support_on_Nokia_devices